# Does ExtendableEvent.waitUntil() has any timeout or can be aborted?

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, service-worker-events

The service worker install event is given an instance of ExtendableEvent to its handler which you can use it to pause registration by calling waitUntil() method and pass a promise. e.g.

```
// inside service worker
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
    ...
    event.waitUntil(promise1);
    console.log("waiting for promise1");
});
```

My question is that, is there any way to cancel the wait after some time  or that SW registration remains indefinitely in the " trying to install" phase as long as that promise is not resolved or rejected.
Since I didn't see any timeout or abort option with waitUntil method.

Answer (score 1):

First, a nit: `InstallEvent`'s `waitUntil()` method does not pause registration. Service worker registration is distinct from the execution of the `install` phase of the registered service worker. (There is more background [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71210703/serviceworker-registration-in-chrome-sometimes-hangs/71240372#71240372).)

If you call `waitUntil()` inside of an `install` event handler, the service worker won't progress out of the `installing` state until either the promise resolves, or until a browser-specific timeout is reached, at which point I *believe* the promise will be treated as if it rejected. This timeout is not part of the service worker specification and can vary from browser to browser, so I would not rely on it being set to any specific value.

It sounds like you'd like to impose your own deterministic timeout with a hard limit on how long users might have to wait. If that's the case, you can do that by creating a new `Promise` and inside of that, combining your original async operation with a call to `setTimeout()`.

```js
const TIMEOUT_MS = ...;

self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
  const originalPromise = ...;

  const promiseWithTimeout = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const id = setTimeout(
      () => reject(new Error(`Timed out after ${TIMEOUT_MS}ms`)),
      TIMEOUT_MS,
    );

    originalPromise.then((result) => {
      clearTimeout(id);
      resolve(result);
    }).catch((err) => reject(err));
  });

  event.waitUntil(promiseWithTimeout);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I used the word registration where I meant installation. So, it seems there is nothing in the spec to make the install wait time-bounded.

Comment: @pref yes interesting, but surely all browsers and runtimes still have some kind of timeout but it must be hardcoded somewhere in their implementation.